# Create a new unit type for CSS with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Bit of a strange question.  Perhaps more of a curiosity.

I'd like to be able to add a new unit type to CSS.  So at the moment, we have "px", "%", "em" and that kind of thing.

As I know the size of the screen I will be on, I'd like to add "mm" for millimetres.  Is this possible?  The closest thing I can find out there is cssHooks, but that would be a LOT of hooks!

Cheers!

Comment: You *could* hack jQuery to have it support arbitrary units: http://jsfiddle.net/7rRn7/. Not recommended, though, but since you asked it as a curiosity you may find it interesting.

Comment: thanks!  That's pretty close to what I'm after :)

Answer (score 5):

CSS already has has this unit ([docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths)), so you can [use it right away](http://jsfiddle.net/DGYcp/).

Note that this will probably not give the exact dimensions in millimiters on the screen. CSS assumes a a pixel density of 96dpi.

Answering your specific question: **no, it's not possible to create a new CSS unit with JavaScript**. But, if you know the size of the screen, and the resolution you're using (in pixels), you can always calculate the equivalent in pixels. For example, if you're using `1024x768px` on a screen that is `40x30cm`, you can assume a `cm` (`10mm`) is around `26px`.

Comment: Note that this has very little to do with the actual screen size in mm.

Comment: @David Right, added a little more explanation.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way of overriding the 96 dpi default?  My physical screen size and dpi changes while its rendering - so I'd ideally like it to be able to react to that.  I guess I was just hoping for a silver bullet function I could override somewhere deep in the window.renderengine.some.deep.dark.corner.of.it

Comment: @John I don't think so. And I'm afraid browsers may not even be consistent on their implementations. I guess you'll have to use a workaround. If you know the physical dimensions of the display, you can use `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` to figure out the resolution in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You do know that millimeters and centimeters are already available in CSS.

Available CSS units:

- `em` (*ems*, the height of the element's font)
- `ex` (*x-height*, the height of the letter "x")
- `px` (*pixels*, relative to the canvas resolution)
- `in` (*inches*; 1in=2.54cm)
- `cm` (*centimeters*; 1cm=10mm)
- `mm` (*millimeters*)
- `pt` (*points*; 1pt=1/72in)
- `pc` (*picas*; 1pc=12pt)

Absolute units are generally only used for other media types, like printing etc.

You set them with jQuery like so :

```
$(element).css('height', '50mm');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YNDYz/)

Answer (score 1):

If your screen is **not** 96dpi, you *could* use a **CSS pre-processor** that supports variables, like **[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)**. That way, you could define a variable that scales from millimetres to pixels:

```
$mm = 2.83 // for 72dpi (72/25.4≈2.83)

.content
    width: 150px*$mm
```

It's not very elegant, though. It requires pre-processing all your stylesheets, and the syntax (`npx * $mm`) is awkward.

If the DPI of the screen is variable, you could try using [media queries](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32) to respond to the screen size. I suspect you could define `$mm` based on the screen size. Unfortunately, as far as I know it's not currently possible to target based on DPI. Webkit-based mobile browsers support `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio`, but that is not the same.

Comment: Is there no way of overriding this value of 96dpi?  My screen is based on a projector and has a variable DPI and size.

Comment: @John: That contradicts what you said in your question... Anyway, I updated the answer.